# Simple string comparison function

Tags: c, strings

A small, simple yet always needed function to compare two strings for equality.

```
int strequal (const char *str1, const char *str2) 
{
    while(1)
    {
        if((*str1) != (*str2))
        {
            return 1; /* Not Equal*/
        }
        else if((*str1) == '\0')
        {
            return 0; /* Equal */
        }

        str1++;
        str2++;
    }

    return 0; /* Equal*/
}

int main ()
{
    const char *str1 = "Hello";
    const char *str2 = "Hi";

    printf("Strings are equal? %s\n", strequal(str1, str2)? "NO":"YES");

    return 0;
}
```

The performance is the main focus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want better performance, you should be using the standard library function `strcmp()`:

```
#include <string.h>
int str_unequal(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    return strcmp(str1, str2) != 0;
}
```

The library function can take advantage of the target processor, possibly comparing multiple characters per iteration, which you can't easily do in a portable C program.

---

Other issues in the function:

- `strequal()` is a name reserved for future library extension, as is any identifier beginning `str` followed immediately by a letter.
- `equal` is misleading in the name, as it returns true only when the strings are *unequal*.
- `while (1)` is dubious practice, especially given that there's a natural terminating condition (end of one of the strings).
- Unnecessary parentheses around the result of dereference operator `*` - that's higher precedence than comparisons.
- The final `return 0;` is unreachable.

Problems with the test program:

- Uses `printf` without including `<stdio.h>`.
- Should explicitly state that `main()` accepts no arguments (i.e. `int main(void)`).
- Only tests a small portion of the functionality (no tests of two equal strings, or one that's a prefix of the other).
- Always returns a success status, even when the function is wrong.

---

Modified function and tests:

```
int str_equal(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    while (*s1) {
        if (*s1++ != *s2++) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return !*s2;
}

#include <stdio.h>
int test_str_equal(int expected, const char *a, const char *b)
{
    int actual = str_equal(a, b);
    if (actual == expected) { return 0; }
    fprintf(stderr, "\"%s\"==\"%s\" should return %d\n", a, b, expected);
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    return test_str_equal(1, "", "")
        +  test_str_equal(0, "", "x")
        +  test_str_equal(0, "x", "")
        +  test_str_equal(1, "x", "x")
        +  test_str_equal(0, "x", "y")
        +  test_str_equal(0, "x", "xy")
        +  test_str_equal(0, "xy", "x")
        +  test_str_equal(0, "xx", "xy")
        +  test_str_equal(1, "xy", "xy");
}
```

Comment: The result of main can also be a bitmask representation of the test comparisons. Each rval of `test_str_equal` can be bit shifted by its enumerator and OR'd on a value. `strcmp` will of course always be faster and in normal practice should always be used. That applies to all standard functions where optimized asm branching is present. I am not sure if `strcmp` would usually compare two bytes a time, but I think it would probably use inline memcmp calls. The last return even unreachable is not an anti-pattern in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, bitmask is another option (for a small number of tests; observe that  we already exceed the number of bits we can portably report in POSIX) - my main point was to not return zero if the tests fail.  I haven't looked closely at any `strcmp()` implementation, but I wouldn't be surprised to see it working in larger units than two bytes - more like the platform's `int` or `long` at a time, and perhaps more when targeting ISAs such as AVX2.

Comment: To me, unreachable code is a problem because it represents _untested_ code.  And the code quality tools I use complain about it; the easiest way to shut them up is to remove the problem.  :-)

Comment: I also haven't, but my guess is that so long as the strings are not aligned, it will compare them byte-by-byte and memcmp them otherwise. It should probably also inline the entire function it if the compared string is less than 4 characters or something (we all know the overhead of a call is significant).

Comment: Well for the sake of argument even an 2002 program that I use, which uses interpreted C89 semantics complained about "unreachable code". Though, unreachable code is tied to the code logic and that isn't something reliable. In this particular case it is too evident that the return is unreachable only because of the awful practice of `while(1)` but it's still wrapped in a cond.  It may also be problematic in some cases where MT or re-entrancy has been introduced, also debuggers and code injections. In fact some time ago I wrote a program that injects a longjump and tries to get around deadlocks

Comment: A singular weakness to `test_str_equal(1, "x", "x")` is that both `"x"` may point to the same string.  Test code needs to insure different string addresses compare as equal. Overall, good answer.